# Why does std::binary_function<...> not have an operator() method?

Tags: c++, function, functional-programming

I noticed that `std::binary_function<...>` [is only a struct with typedefs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function). At the link, it specifically says:

> binary_function does not define `operator()`; it is expected that derived classes will define this.

This seems nonsensical to me. What's the point of this class (or struct) if you can inherit it, or instantiate it, without having a function at all? Or are the semantics different than they seem to me?

Comment: That's the whole point of the structure, that you inherit it and implement the call-operator function. That makes it easy to create other functions which take `std::binary_function` as an argument. Sure it can be done using templates, but by using `std::binary_function` you are explicit in saying what is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that C++11 deprecated and C++17 removes `binary_function`.

`binary_function` was simply a helper to create the typedefs used by the (also now deprecated) function adapters, e.g. `not2`. Remember that before `auto` and `decltype` were available it was hard or impossible to deduced those types, so they had to be provided manually. Also, what would be the point of defining `operator()`? There could not be a possible implementation and making it `pure virtual` would be a significant performance drain.

Comment: "There could not be a possible implementation" <- That's the case even without an operator(). As for making it pure virtual - would it really be a performance drain? I mean, operator() for binary_function's is now used (essentially) only via template specification. But when this happens, you know what the type really is at compile time and can just inline the function call or at least make a function call without using the vtable. Or am I wrong?

Comment: A guiding principle in the design of the C++ language and C++ standard library is the zero-overhead principle (don't pay for what you don't use) (see Stroustrup's Design and Evolution of C++). `virtual` functions are a often a violation of that principle and can be avoided in many cases.

Comment: And yes, my applications are full with tiny functors which often carry no data at all. `vtables` would be a huge performance problem.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, there is no implementation of `operator()` that could be put in the base class, and that would be of any use.

Secondly, any "normal" use of a class derived from `binary_function` will at some point call `operator()` on it anyway, resulting in a compiler error if the class doesn't implement it. This is because `binary_function` is not a polymorphic base class -- nobody should ever be trying to call `operator()` via a pointer or reference to `binary_function`.

If it helps make sense of the situation, think of `binary_function` as a tag or a mixin, not as an interface.

As to *why* it's not a polymorphic base class with a pure virtual `operator()`: the standard libraries just weren't designed that way. They were designed to use templates, not runtime polymorphism. Polymorphic functor wrappers were added in C++11 as `std::function`, but `binary_function` has nothing to do with that.

Comment: 1. it's a structure with no data anyway, just make it virtual. 2. By this logic it can be an empty structure, since any normal use will require the parameter types and return type, so let's just make it an empty structure then. I do think of binary_function as a mix-in - and it's a mixin which is supposed to have an operator(). 3. I believe you're making a homunculus argument: It's that way because it was designed that way; and if we don't use runtime polymorphism, why not just ditch this class altogether? It's a binary function if it can be used like a binary function.

Answer (score 2):

That's answered in the text that immediately follows your quote.

> Some standard library function object adaptors, such as std::not2, **require the function objects they adapt to have certain types defined**; std::not2 requires the function object being adapted to have two types named first_argument_type and second_argument_type. Deriving function objects that take two arguments from binary_function is an easy way to make them compatible with those adaptors.

That is the purpose of `std::binary_function`.  To guarantee certain typedefs.