# passing interface or reference to a function as parameter

Tags: c++, oop, parameters

I have wrapper class and I have pass its object to a function.

```
class wrapper
{
/// some functionality
}
```

What will be better to pass as reference to the class  like

```
fun(wrapper & ob)
```

or to new Interface that is inherited by wrapper like:

```
class Interface
{
}
 ....
class wrapper:public Interface
 ...
fun(Interface& ob)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "better"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Interface` approach is better if:

1. You want to follow [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and be able in future to replace `wrapper` with some other class that implements `Interface`
2. You want to hide `wrapper`'s implementation from `fun`'s user - i.e. you won't need to #include `wrapper.h` before `fun` declaration
3. and so on..

It is *generally* better to go with `Interface` to abstract implementation from interface, BUT also do not forget about [“not pay for what you don't use”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304992/how-can-i-better-learn-to-not-pay-for-what-you-dont-use) principle, i.e. if you know that you won't need any implementation of `Interface` other than `wrapper` soon enough and `wrapper.h` #inclusion is not a problem for your project than going with `Interface` will be [over-design](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/over-designed)

Answer (score 4):

If you want your function to only accept instances of the `wrapper` class, use

```
fun(wrapper& ob)
```

or

```
fun(const wrapper& ob)
```

if you do not intend to modify it.

If you want your function to accept anything that implements the `Interface` class (only really useful if there are more classes than just `wrapper` inheriting from `Interface`), then use:

```
fun(Interface& ob)
```

or

```
fun(const Interface& ob)
```

The choice depends on the use-case.

Comment: If I have in wrapper class 2 public functions

    class wrapper
    {public:
    fun1();
    fun2();
    }
but I want to use only fun1 in function fun is it better to specify with interface

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev Think about design of _interfaces_ themselves first, not about one particular usage scenario (`fun`) that you have today