# How could I make the access of commonly shared object thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition, critical-section

I have searched through the entire SO forum but couldn't find any plausible answers. I know resource sharing can be made threadsafe by using synchronisation mechanisms like mutexes and semaphores but my question is different. Let's say you have a `Logger logger`  object. Which is passed by reference to all the running threads. This `logger` object has a `Logger::log` function where are a resource (log file) is accessed by multiple threads. I can wrap this critical section with mutexes with the method in order to prevent race conditions. But how can I prevent the race condition which might occur when multiple threads access the shared `Logger logger` object. I could pass a common mutex lock along with the `Logger logger` object and try to acquire the object before using it but that solution is not elegant. Whats the best way to prevent race condition in this given scenario?

Comment: What else than calling `log` on `logger` can other threads do to it?

Comment: Nothing much besides logging. Once the `Logger logger` is instantiated by the main thread; it will get passed by reference to other threads which needs logging capabilities. Other threads do not do much besides using the `log` method

Comment: Then - nothing to worry. One solution you already provided - add mutex as member in logger and protect its log function. Other solution is to wrap unsynchronized logger with synchronized logger - the class that has mutex and logger (possible reference).

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate on synchronized logger?

Comment: "I know resource sharing can be made threadsafe by using synchronisation mechanisms like mutexes and semaphores but my question is different. " Is it? "What's the best way?" is not a StackOverflow type question.

Comment: I added more explanation to my point as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More in sync with [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and C++ idea of [not to pay for what you dont use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304992/how-can-i-better-learn-to-not-pay-for-what-you-dont-use) is to have `Logger` class responsible only for logging. Imagine that you want to reuse it for logging in single threaded application - then why to pay for extra synchronization stuff.

But of course for multi-threaded application - you will need synchronization mechanism between threads. One good way to achieve this is to use [Decorator Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) - like below:

```
class ILogger 
{
public: 
   virtual ~ILogger() = default;

   // as many log methods as you need
   virtual void log(args) = 0;
};
```

Then make your Logger deriving from and implementing `ILogger`.

Then define decorator that adds synchronization to it:

```
class SynchronizedLogger : public ILogger 
{
public: 
   SynchronizedLogger (ILogger& logger) : logger(logger) {} 

   // as many log methods as you need
   void log(args) override
   {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(logGuard);
       logger.log(args);
   }

private:
   std::mutex logGuard;
   ILogger& logger; 
};
```

You only have to ensure that all threads that will use logging starts after construction of `SynchronizedLogger`  and stops before its destruction:

```
int main() {
   Logger logger{...}; 
   SynchronizedLogger syncLogger{logger};

   std::thread t1([&syncLogger] { syncLogger.log("T1"); });
   std::thread t2([&syncLogger] { syncLogger.log("T2"); });
   std::thread t3([&syncLogger] { syncLogger.log("T3"); });
   std::thread t4([&syncLogger] { syncLogger.log("T4"); });

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How is this gonna solve the problem? When multiple threads access the `SynchronizedLogger sLogger` object then there is gonna be still a race condition right? Because `SynchronizedLogger sLogger` is still a shared resource which is not wrapped by any synchronised locks? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No it is not  if its construction happens e.g. in main thread before all client thread starts and  destruction happens after all thread stops.